# Bash Scripting, Respond to Keypress

Tags: bash, terminal

I built a tiny menu to use in a bash terminal with multiple options to select via number keys.

```
#!/bin/bash
PS3='Teleport to ... '
options=("→ option 1" "→ option 2" "Quit")
select opt in "${options[@]}"
do
    case $opt in
        "→ option 1")
            echo "option 1"
            break
            ;;
        "→ option 2")
            echo "option 2"
            break
            ;;
        "Quit")
            break
            ;;
        *) echo invalid option
            break
            ;;
    esac
done
```

At the moment I still need to confirm the selection by pressing *enter*. Is it possible to make the script respond to the input of the first pressed key directly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`read -n 1` reads one character. You cannot use `select` with it, though, so you have to write the `while` loop yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Yep, with `bash` (and not `sh`!) you can use something like:

```
_KEY=
read -d '' -sn1 _KEY
```